# proc_open Too many open files in long running Symfony Console app

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-components

I built a console app with Symfony Console component. It supposed to be run for 5 hours. But after running 2 hours i have a `proc_open(): unable to create pipe Too many open files` error in `Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php` on line 985.

I tried `gc_collect_cycles` in my loop, but got the same error.

Is this a Symfony Console component bug or i should not run an app for this long (but i have to)?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same error with a Symfony web-app, and [restarting PHP](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-restart-php-service-command/) resolved it.

I appreciate that you can't do that in the midst of your command's 5-hour run, but maybe doing it immediately beforehand will get PHP in a clean enough state to give you the full 5 hours?

(Also, this post is the only one I found about my problem, so I wanted to add this here in case others have the same issue as me!)

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to:
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47396

Apparently you're working on a lot of resources in your app. It's not a Symfony Console bug, it's a PHP bug.

You can use another programming language or modify your program in order to open less files.